# End of playback detection in AudioTrack is not working

Tags: java, android, audio, audiotrack

This is the code I am using:

```
void playSound(){
    final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
    // audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(generatedSnd.length/2);
    audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(1);
    audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(new AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioTrack track) {
            // nothing to do
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerReached(AudioTrack track) {
            // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio track end of file reached...");
            // messageHandler.sendMessage(messageHandler.obtainMessage(PLAYBACK_END_REACHED));
            Log.d("MY LOG", "Audio track end of file reached...");
            bitPatternValTextView.setText("End of play");
        }
    });
    audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
    audioTrack.play();
}
```

The `playSound()` function is defined inside

> public class InSituActivity extends ActionBarActivity{...}

My assumption was that when the playback of the AudioTrack reached the Nth audio sample (each N being a short or 2 bytes) then `audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(N);` would cause `onMarkerReached(AudioTrack track)` to be called. However as shown in my example code I have tried both `generatedSnd.length/2` (generatedSnd[] is an array of bytes that contains the audio samples I want to play) as well as using small constant values such 1, 10 or 20, and `onMarkerReached()` does not seem to get called in any of those situations. What is wrong here and how do I fix it? I want to be able to play another sound when the current AudioTrack finishes playback. The playSound() function  itself will be called in a thread (seperate from the UI thread).

Here is where I got the code from:
[How to tell when AudioTrack object has finished playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643338/how-to-tell-when-audiotrack-object-has-finished-playing)

Other references:
[AudioTrack: how to detect end of sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642704/audiotrack-how-to-detect-end-of-sound)
[Confusion about Thread life and AudioTrack in android java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541201/confusion-about-thread-life-and-audiotrack-in-android-java)

Comment: You supposed to use file length in number of frames with setNotificationMarkerPosition instead of 1. BTW it should be large number.

Comment: 1 is just a test number, if it was working I should have seen some notification in the logcat

Comment: If you use separate thread,  try MODE_STREAM, and feed AudioTrack in a loop until the end of data

Comment: ok that seems to work, but why isn't it working for static?

Comment: what do you mean by feed audiotrack? I have all the audio samples I need to generate in the generatedSnd array, I think it would be better to play everything as static

Comment: by the way, I changed to MODE_STREAM before you edited your comment, so currently in my code the only difference is that I have changed MODE_STATIC to MODE_STREAM

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you: mine listener is getting called in static mode,  no problems at all

Comment: could you share that section of your code please?

Comment: sure http://pastebin.com/yz2qjneH

Comment: could not using `setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener()` be the reason for the difference?

Comment: what you mean: "could not using"?

Comment: could it be that not using setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener() is causing the problem in my code?

Comment: ??? you are using it: audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(new ...

Comment: oh yeah didn't notice it sorry

Comment: please excuse this I am still not very familiar with android

Answer (score -1):

maybe too late for an answer, but this worked for me. I was not getting onMarkerReached() callback either.
I just increased the static stream size by a large number. May not work for MODE_STREAM or for different buffer sizes. Works for all the buffer sizes I need which is few 10s of seconds max for my use cases.
Try changing this line in your code and see what happens:

```
int magic_number = 1000; // try with different values. Maybe make it 10% of generatedSnd.length?
final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
        AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC + magic_number);
```